# How to concatenate a named textblock in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't figure out how to call several similarly named WPF TextBlocks in a for loop.

In WPF I have several TextBlocks that are each inside of a grid cell:

```
<TextBlock Name="Banner0" />
<TextBlock Name="Banner1" />
<TextBlock Name="Banner2" />
```

For example those three are in Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0", Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1", Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2", respectively.

In C# I am able to change the text in the above TextBlocks with the following code:

```
Banner0.Text = "Sample Text";
Banner1.Text = "Sample Text";
Banner2.Text = "Sample Text";
```

However what I want to do, but can't figure out how to do is change it this way.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
   { 
       Banneri.Text = "Sample Text"; 
   }
```

I understand why I can't do Banneri, but can't figure out how to achieve that concept within a for loop.

Also the text will not be the same in each TextBlock, but for simplicity I used "Sample Text" in all three, as this is not the area that is causing difficulty.

Comment: The Text property of the individual TextBlocks should be bound to a property in view model, e.g. in a collection of data item objects. Search the web for MVVM.

Comment: Otherwise, a simple array like `var textBlocks = new TextBlock[] { Banner0, Banner1, Banner2 }` should also work.

Comment: You could also iterate over all TextBlock children of their parent common parent element: `foreach (var textblock in panel.Children.OfType<TextBlock>()) { … }`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! The MVVM opened a whole rabbit hole, of stuff I was unaware of. Will delve into that more.

Comment: I was trying to do the children method, but think I either don't grasp it enough. Or my WPF is not laid out correct. But the Array does work, and for the time, will be using that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to iterate them would probably be to put them in an array.

```
// put them together
TextBlock[] banners = new [] {Banner0, Banner1, Banner2};

// iterate like this
for(var i = 0; i < banners.Length; i++){
    banners[i].Text = "Sample Text";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. Was hoping for a way to convert something like "banner" + "1" to textblock tb, but I can't find away. Will mark as correct as this does the trick!